# trapped in vim debug window after git commit w/o message

Tags: git, macos, vim, terminal, vi

I am learning to use git and I am familiar with vi which I am using from the terminal of my MacOS.

I don't know if the problem is related to the terminal or to the editor config of git, however when I commit without including a message with '-m "message" '

```
git commit
```

git opens a default message through vi or vim on my terminal but it does it splitting the window and including some type of debug window as shown in the screenshots below:

[image: you notice the bar below with the permanent 'Eval:']
[image: from here on I am trapped forever...]

I tried everything:

```
:quit, :x, :qw!, :exit, ...
```

not even

```
ctrl + c
```

seems to work... is it my terminal under MacOS ? Is it git which opens vim with debug mode if the message is not added to the commit ? In this case, is there a way to config git in order to use vim without the debug window open ?

I know that you can select your editor via

```
git config --global core.editor "vim"
```

but my problem is this debugging sub-window, not vim itself.

I will avoid to commit w/o message attached and it will solve the problem but I would like to know how we escape from this vim window (in case I will have to face the problem and not having any other choice).

Many thanks in advance !

Comment: That is strange...just so you know, I'm on a Mac as well, and this doesn't happen for me...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This does seem to be `emacs` not `Vim`, based on the window's title. You can quit `emacs` with `[Ctrl-x][Ctrl-c]`.

Comment: Wow, it was that simple...I don't know how I have not thought about emacs..
Many thanks ! (it worked of course)